# Serve multiple domains on one ip and one port

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, https

I want to serve multiple domains on my CentOS server. I run servers on http. Now I want to run these servers on https using another certificates.

I written ssl.conf like this.

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt
  ServerName www.example.com:443
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/two.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/two.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt
  ServerName two.example.com:443
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/two
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove `:443` from `two.example.com:443`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.  The reason is that the URL in the client browser's request is encrypted along with the rest of the request, when it reaches your server.  As a result, there is no way to decrypt it without knowing which host (and which certificate) it was intended for.

In the past, I've solved this in two different ways.  The first requires firewall access and more than one public IP address, the second requires a more fancy SSL certificate.

1. I've got multiple SSL websites running by running them on different ports, then directing SSL traffic from different IP addresses at the firewall to different ports on the server.  So - one server, one internal IP address, but a separate external IP address for each site and using port forwarding at the firewall to modify the incoming port number and thus direct the traffic.
2. The other option is to have a single certificate that works across multiple domains.  This is known as a SAN (Secure Alternative Name) certificate.  Geotrust, for example, do one that you can add up to 25 domain names too.  This is the easier way, because when the request arrives, each site is using the same certificate so the request can be decrypted and handled in the way you describe.  These certificates are a lot more expensive than the basic SSL certificates, but to be fair they are a little bit better.

Comment: So you mean I can't serve multiple domains on one ip and one port using free certificates.

Comment: If I following your first condition, I want to reference with your ssl.conf file.
If you give or write on here, thanks.

Comment: To your first comment - that is correct, you can't.

Comment: Then I will following different ports and different ip addresses, right?

Comment: With regard to ssl.conf, I'm afraid mine wouldn't work for you - as it was a Plesk setup.  However you should be able to re-write your own, just using a different port number (e.g. 444) for the second site.

Comment: Then how you can set different ip addresses on your server?

Comment: Different ports on the server - same IP address.  On the firewall, you set one external IP address to forward to your server on port 443, and a second external IP address to forward to your server on port 444.  Of course I'm assuming you are behind a NAT-ing firewall

Comment: And is another settings on my settings like you?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand that question.

Comment: my means SSLEngine, SSLCertificateFile, etc.
is these config same with your config?

Comment: If you are editing SSLCertificateFile on Apache, you need a block like this for each site:  
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>  
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2  
ServerName www.yourdomain.com  
SSLEngine on  
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt  
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key  
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt  
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Sorry - that pasted badly because it was in a comment.  You can see the block structure here: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm

Comment: It is possible to run multiple ssl sites on one IP using SNI and it can be done with free certs. see https://letsencrypt.org/. It didnt used to be possible but most modern browsers support SNI now

Comment: Hi, Neil P.
I added <VirtualHost> tags as your examples.
But it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Hi, Vagnerr,
I can't find any information about ssl in letsencrypt.org.
Give me detail url, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Vagnerr - I learnt something today!  Zuiche, if this will work for you it is an easier option than the IP mapping.  The docs for LetsEncrypt are here: https://letsencrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help any more with your SSLCertificateFile - its been a long time since I've worked on those but there is plenty of documentation around.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [Name-Based VirtualHosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) using SSL/TLS.
This by default is not possible because of the way SSL/TLS and Http works(Take a look [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)).

May be you want to try [SSL with Virtual Hosts Using SNI](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) but this also will be difficult with existing certificates.

Comment: I want to know what is difference with my method and Name-Based VirtualHosts.

Comment: Using the same IP for multiple sites is named Name-based Virtual Hosting (in contrast to IP-based Virtual Hosting). You just need to add the NameVirtualHost Apache Directive to the configuration you have to support this. But this will not play with SSL as said above.

Comment: So I added "NameVirtualHost *:443" line in ssl.conf.
But it isn't work yet.

Comment: Yes, that's what we are saying. Your configuration will not work. There is only a possibility to work with SNI, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I want to know openssl 0.9.8.e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008 supports SNI.